# Retain spark node history

Tags: apache-spark

How to retain spark worker and master node history such as completed applications , completed drivers in a cluster. When there is a restart all these history are lost. Is there any specific config to enable for maintaining the history.

Enabled spark event log in spark-defaults.conf

```
    spark.eventLog.enabled    true
    spark.eventLog.dir   file:////app/spark/logs/data/event_log_dir
```

But still unable to retain the history

Answer (score 1):

There is inbox solution - Spark History Server

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact

Comment: When using the file-system provider class, the base logging directory must be supplied in the spark.history.fs.logDirectory configuration option, and should contain sub-directories that each represents an application’s event logs.
The spark jobs themselves must be configured to log events, and to log them to the same shared, writable directory. For example, if the server was configured with a log directory of hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs, then the client-side options would be:
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs

Comment: Here I'm using local filesystem path and "spark.eventLog.dir" is required for Spark History Server

Answer (score 0):

Spark UI is available only while application is running.
There is a Spark History Server tool, that allows you to see the UI after the application is finished.

More information is in Spark documentation:
[Spark: Monitoring and Instrumentation - Viewing After the Fact](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact)

Comment: When using the file-system provider class, the base logging directory must be supplied in the spark.history.fs.logDirectory configuration option, and should contain sub-directories that each represents an application’s event logs.

The spark jobs themselves must be configured to log events, and to log them to the same shared, writable directory. For example, if the server was configured with a log directory of hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs, then the client-side options would be:
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs

Comment: Here I'm using local filesystem path and "spark.eventLog.dir" is required for Spark History Server